# Orphan products in catalog_product_entity

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, product-attribute

I have three odd products in my catalog_product_entity table.  I can't tell where they are from or why they are there. They do not come up if I put the ID into the magento "manage products".  They have no attributes assigned to them in any of the catalog_product_entity_* tables.

```
id   - SKU
2554 - - Yellow|product_list::N|product_list_child::|vm_list_header::|v
2604 - - Yellow|product_list::N|product_list_child::|vm_list_header::|v
2605 - - Yellow|product_list::N|product_list_child::|vm_list_header::|v
```

From the createdat and updatedat dates, they may have been errant imports from when the previous web company made the site.  Just want to make sure before I go and delete them. Is there any other place I should look for a relation to these items?

Answer (score 0):

There are many tables associated and related to `catalog_product_entity`. However, as you have rogue entries in there and under the assumption that they don't show up in the admin, you can safely remove the records directly from `catalog_product_entity`. There are constraints on the relational tables, so you'll delete most, if not all, of the associated data in other tables.